# how to get default value dependent dropdown selected for edit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have 3 dependent dropdown. 1. Select province 2. Select amphur 3. select district

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#student_province').change(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {student_province: $(this).val()},
                    url: '../script/amphur.php',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#student_amphur').html(data);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#student_amphur').change(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {student_amphur: $(this).val()},
                    url: '../script/district.php',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#student_tambon').html(data);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

how to if i come back to edit data i need to show the saved value as selected option. get the default value after to save on db for Edit again.

thank you very very much. and Sorry, my english isn't good

Comment: In your PHP you would have to first get the current values from the database, then when printing your options, you could do something like `<option value='Nai' <?php echo $amphur=='Nai'?'selected':'' ?>>`

Comment: yes i get the current values on the selec option. i already do it

Comment: I guess I'm unclear as to what you're asking then... I interpreted "how to if i come back to edit data i need to show the saved value as selected option" as "How do I show the saved value for the `<select>` as the selected option when returning to the edit page?"...

Comment: web site have 2 role student and admin if student worng input data admin can to edit